# I don't understand logic when i'm using list type variables in the python. Why is it working in that way?

Tags: python, list, logic

Why do we get 1,2,3,4,5 - output after executing this code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = list1
list1.append(5)
print(list2) # it will output 1,2,3,4,5
```

Another case:

```
list1 = 5
list2 = list1
list1 += 1
print(list2) # it will output 5
```

Why is it working in that way?

Comment: Well, I am not sure the other post will really answer his question @CDJB.
The real difference here is that in the first part you are working with a `list` and in the second part with a `float` which is a different datatype and therefore behaves differently.

Comment: @CDJB I don't think your comment answers their question either. They are not asking how to clone a list, but rather why it works that way

Comment: If you read the answers to the question - rather than just the title - they answer the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is clear to me now. I was a bit confused about it. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @CDJB I did, but in that answer they only explain how lists work. The difference between floats and lists is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to understand the difference between a variable and an object.

A variable is something that has a name and that you can refer to, which is a way of accessing an object.

An object is a "data" that is stored in your computer temporarily.

When you create your first list, you create two things : an object of type list (`[1,2,3,4]`) and a way of accessing it, `list1` (a variable).

When you define `list2`, you don't create another list. You create another access to the list previously created and refereable with `list1`, since you tell the program that `list2` points where `list1` does. Therefore, using `list1` or `list2` doesn't make any difference, both refer to the same object. You can access the latter with either of the two, same result.

About your second example, you first "link" the two variables as you did in the first example, but when you do the operate `+=`, you break that link because `=` changes the object your variable is pointing to. Therefore, the variable are not "synchronized" anymore

Comment: Thank you for the reply.